# Is Microsoft going to support SQL Server 2008 with LINQ in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql-server, linq, visual-studio-2010

Is Microsoft going to support the features of SQL Server 2008 such as Hierarchyid and Filestream with LINQ in Visual Studio 2010 at last?

Thanks

P.S: Tired of having features in SQL Server that Microsoft's own tools don't support. Please let me know if it's worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there haven't been any official announcements, MS has made it pretty clear that Entity Framework is the future, and that significant enhancements won't be made in LINQ to SQL ([here](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40)'s a list of what's new in L2S for 4.0). L2S isn't going anywhere, but I wouldn't expect to see any of these features get lit up anytime soon, either.

Comment: Even if the future is Entity Framework,Entity framework doesn't support the same either I guess

Comment: I wouldn't expect so- EF supports any DB with its generic provider model (as L2S was supposed to, but was cut in 3.5B2). It's pretty tough to surface DB-specific features in a generic API. I'm sure it could be done, but it doesn't look like it's happening in 4.0.